# Why CloudFormation replace resource during adding resource tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

As described in the documentation, I think CloudFormation will update with no interruption just by changing to add a tag.

In my case, another team uses terraform to add tag resources with generic tags, and my team uses CloudFormation to update the application-specific tags. Does this cause replacement...?
Also, this only occurred for limited resources such as security groups.

Does anyone know anything about this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudformation is a Jealous Tool - in otherwords, if it doesn't control the Resource in entirety it will overwrite changes, assuming that the changes are in a location it thinks it has to update.

In order for CloudFormation stacks not to do work that is not needed they generate ChangeSets - indicating what resources need updating/rebuilding/ect. If you don't change anything in the *template* (or your cdk stack) then the ChangeSet won't update that resource cause nothing needs to change. Depending on the resource (and it varies from service to service) sometimes changes made outside of CloudFormation control (by either other services like Terraform or by manual changes in the console - both of which are referred to as 'Drift') dont get overwritten by the stack updating (most common I can think of is API gateway - adding / deleting resources or methods doesn't always get re done by a redeploy of the stack.

However, for things like tags, yes - it will overwrite any changes made in there at any time and reapply the tags as of the moment it deploys - (again, depending on the Service) often even if there are no other changes to deploy for that given resource. I suspect the reason for this is because of the way AWS uses tags on the backend to sort and search resources.

Your best bet is to pick one service and do everything with it.

Comment: Thank you! I understand. I'll consider to choose one to avoid these kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

Each of these two tools will overwrite the tags the other created. You can configure Terraform to [ignore certain tags](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/guides/resource-tagging#ignoring-changes-in-all-resources) However I'm not sure you can configure CloudFormation to ignore any tags. I think CloudFormation will always delete tags that it doesn't manage. In general it's not going to work well using both CloudFormation and Terraform to manage the same resources.